# Can I 'recompile' table returning functions after that table is ALTER-ed during database migration?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I have a stored procedure that returns a record type. If I ALTER the table this stored procedure returns (let's say I add a column), I have to either disconnect my database session or re-run the `CREATE OR REPLACE`. When I don't I will get the error `wrong record type supplied in RETURN NEXT`.

Here's a script that fails when I run it in a single `psql` session:

```
CREATE TABLE p1(a INT, b TEXT);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION authenticate() RETURNS SETOF p1 as '
DECLARE
    player_row p1;
BEGIN

    -- query is more complicated but always returns zero or one rows
    SELECT p.* INTO player_row
    FROM p1 p;

    IF FOUND THEN
        RETURN NEXT player_row;

        -- more code in here..
    END IF;

    RETURN;
END;' LANGUAGE plpgsql ROWS 1;


ALTER TABLE p1 ADD COLUMN c VARCHAR(2);
INSERT INTO p1 VALUES(1,'a', 'c');
SELECT * FROM AUTHENTICATE();
```

Is there a Postgres command or setting with which I could automate the re-compilation of stored procedures? I tried @vao-tsun's suggestion of running `DISCARD PLANS` after the migrations, but unfortunately it did not help.

Comment: Wow, that's interesting.. the line that fails is the `RETURN NEXT` line, but it works in your example. Thank you very much, I will try to replicate my problem the DB Fiddle you created (didn't know about DB Fiddle, thank you for that as well!)

Comment: ..currently it seems the problem is if I run the whole thing inside a single connection and/or transaction (which is what happens in our testing setup). I don't know what DB Fiddle does behind the scenes, I have to investigate further.

Comment: I will, and thank you, I would like to test a something first though - I've had something urgent fill my time today, thank you for your help so far!

Comment: I think this could be my problem: 'Functions are evaluated the first time that they are called in a session.  At that point the plan for any database operations is done and it is left available for future executions within the same session.' - https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1192554889.10677.176.camel@linda.lfix.co.uk (I've updated my code sample so it is directly runnable)

Comment: No, in the fiddle it works - I suspect it may be splitting various commands across different connections. If I take my block of code and paste it into `psql` all at once it fails.

Comment: yes - I C now. of course `DISCARD PLANS` before next call does not help?.. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-discard.html I thought plpgsql functions plans are not cached though :/

Comment: No, unfortunately. Thank you for all your help, I modified the question now that I (hopefully :) ) understand the problem better. I see the programmatic solution now (drop connection between migrations) but I would prefer a pure PSQL resolution.

Comment: In `psql` you could put a `\c` into the script to establish a new connection

Comment: Thank you, didn't know that either, but my main problem is when running migrations via Flyway in a JVM application. I can program around it now that I know a reconnect solves the problem, still, if I knew how to purge the function cache (or something to that affect :) ), I wouldn't have to :)

Comment: `\c` would be purely `psql` solution, not SQL though

Comment: I just realised, that I worked for me all the time, because I tested behind the `pgpool` with two RO slaves, so load balancer was splitting statements, and as soon as I tried to run it in transaction it failed :) tough week it was... Also I give up finding the reasonable neat solution here (like I was hoping discard would help) and answered with re-recreating function - as you suggest in title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you were looking for this `DO` statement:

```
CREATE TABLE p1(a INT, b TEXT);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION authenticate() RETURNS SETOF p1 as '
DECLARE
    player_row p1;
BEGIN

    -- query is more complicated but always returns zero or one rows
    SELECT p.* INTO player_row
    FROM p1 p;

    IF FOUND THEN
        RETURN NEXT player_row;

        -- more code in here..
    END IF;

    RETURN;
END;' LANGUAGE plpgsql ROWS 1;

ALTER TABLE p1 ADD COLUMN c VARCHAR(2);
INSERT INTO p1 VALUES(1,'a', 'c');

do $$ begin execute pg_get_functiondef('authenticate'::regproc); end; $$;

SELECT * FROM AUTHENTICATE();
```

but as a_horse_with_no_name suggests, you can just `\c` to reconnect with `psql`

Comment: sure, no worries - interesting case you had